# Python Tkinter Edit Menu Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to edit [Menu window](http://prntscr.com/orpwlo). How can i edit it?

This is for Windows.

```
from tkinter import *

Window = Tk()

MB = Menu(Window)
Window.config(menu=MB)

Menubar = Menu(MB)
MB.add_cascade(label="File", menu=Menubar)
Menubar.add_command(label="New File")

#Btn1 = Button(Menubar, width=20, text="Button").pack() #I failed.

Window.mainloop()
```

I tried `Btn1 = Button(Menubar, width=20, text="Button").pack()`
But this one couldn't work.

Comment: Offtopic: please distinct classes in Python (CamelCase; you're doing that right) with instances (all lowercase, you're doing it wrong; window, mb, menubar)

Comment: Okay thanks I'll. I think this better looking.

Comment: Readability counts.

Comment: What do you mean by "edit it"? What sort of edit do you wish to make?

Comment: For example adding buttons, labels or others.

Answer (score 2):

usually you add items to menu like this - but what are looking for?

```py
window = Tk()
mb = Menu(window)  
menu_bar = Menu(mb, tearoff=0)  
menu_bar.add_command(label="New")  
menu_bar.add_command(label="Open")  
menu_bar.add_command(label="Save")  
menu_bar.add_command(label="Save as...")  
menu_bar.add_command(label="Close")  

menu_bar.add_separator()  

menu_bar.add_command(label="Exit", command=window.quit)  

mb.add_cascade(label="File", menu=menu_bar)

top.config(menu=mb)
```

Comment: Works great, except `top.config` I think should be `window.config` in your case?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add arbitrary widgets to a menu. To add items to a menu you must use one of the following functions available on the Menu object:

- `add`
- `add_command`
- `add_cascade`
- `add_checkbutton`
- `add_radiobutton`
- `add_separator`

To add a textual label you can use `add_command` and set the `command` attribute to `None`.

All of these are documented with the Menu widget definition itself, and on just about any site that includes widget documentation.

Comment: Using Himanshu's answer there was no need for `command=None`. You can simply omit `command` as a parameter / argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a control of Menu Bar with Buttons you can do it. All of the code will be in the same file.py .Libraries in Python3 (For Python 2 change to import Tkinter as tk). Later you can redirect to each window with each menu with buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
```

Global list of titles for

```
nombre_ventanas={'PageOne'}
```

One menubar, you need to add similar for each menu that you want to display. menubar_global, menubar1, menubar2, ...

```
def menubar_global(self, root, controller):

    menubar_global = tk.Menu(root)

    page_1 = tk.Menu(menubar_global, tearoff=0)

    # With Submenu for page_1

    page_1_1=tk.Menu(page_1 , tearoff=0)
    page_1_2=tk.Menu(page_1 , tearoff=0)
```

Main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ControlWindow()
    app.mainloop()
```

Class for windows control

```
class ControlWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        self._nombre_ventanas = nombre_ventanas

        for F in self._nombre_ventanas:

            F = eval(F)
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # First window
        self.show_frame(Login)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

        # Title for each page
        self.title(titulo_ventanas[cont._name_for_menu_bar])

        # Here you can add if-sentece for each menubar that you want 
        if cont._name_for_menu_bar != "PageOne":

            # Menu bar
            print("show_frame", cont)
            menubar = frame.menubar(self)
            self.configure(menu=menubar)

        else:
            menubar = 0
            self.configure(menu=menubar)

class Ventana_proveedores(tk.Frame):

    _name_for_menu_bar = "Ventana_proveedores"

    _config = configuracion

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        tk.Button(self, text='Regresar', font=FONT_LABELFRAME,
                command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Ventana_gerente)).grid(row=0, column=0)

    def menubar(self, root):
        return menubar_global(self, root, self.controller)
```

Later Each Page need to have this configuration

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    _name_for_menu_bar = "PageOne"


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

    def menubar(self, root):
        return menubar_global(self, root, self.controller)
```